# What's the relationship between LensKit 3.0-SNAPSHOT and LensKit 3.0-T*?

Tags: maven, lenskit

I was looking for `LensKit 3.0-T5 API` but I only found [LensKit 3.0-SNAPSHOT API](http://lenskit.org/master/apidocs/). So what's the relationship between `LensKit 3.0-SNAPSHOT` and `3.0-T5` (or any other 3.0-T* versions)?

My guess is that 3.0-SNAPSHOT is the API that describes quite accurately any of the 3.0-T* versions. If not, which `updated`, `well-documented` version of LensKit should I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T5 are 'teaching snapshots' (effectively milestone releases, but early in the 3.0 dev cycle) of 3.0. 3.0-SNAPSHOT has seen quite a few changes since -T5. T1-5 are pretty similar to each other, mostly bug fixes between them.

You can find documentation for the -T series here: http://mooc.lenskit.org/

You can also find current `-SNAPSHOT` JavaDoc here: http://lenskit.org/master/apidocs/

[current as of 7/12/2016] We expect to make a -T6 release within the next week that contains the current 3.0-SNAPSHOT code, and will be updating the teaching site accordingly. I hope to be able to cut the final 3.0 release - and update the http://lenskit.org web site - by mid August.

I would recommend either 2.2.1 or -SNAPSHOT, planning to upgrade to -T6 or 3.0 final.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment! Really looking forward to the -T6 release! I don't find any Maven repo for 3.0-SNAPSHOT so I'm gonna go with -T5 for now. Is -T6 and the final 3.0 release significantly (drastically) different from -T5?

Comment: In addition, I'm following [an example for content-based filtering](https://github.com/eugenelin89/recommender_content_based) that uses LensKit 2.0. I'm trying to update the codes to 3.0-T5 but having troubles with deprecated classes and methods. Some of them don't point to alternatives in the 2.2.1 documentation. Do you have any example more up-to-date than 2.0 (even better if it's in content-based filtering), or any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @S.H. -T6 does have some pretty significant differences, particularly in data access. -SNAPSHOT is on the Sonatype snapshot respository. I just checked, and it looks like none of our current examples have been updated to 3.0 yet. I've filed a bug to update the most relevant (https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit-algorithm-example/issues/1)